# How to display a few articles within a module?

Tags: joomla, module

So basically, I wish to load a few article posts within a category to a module.

These article posts must be the latest 3 or so that have been published.

I have searched far and wide for answers, but I couldn't seem to find anything. I found an extension called 'Articles Anywhere', although I don't think it can do what I am asking exactly.
http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/articlesanywhere

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: How do you want them displayed? Entire article? Just title? Just to read more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, Joomla has this module in core. It's called the Latest News module. You can read more about it at http://docs.joomla.org/Help25:Extensions_Module_Manager_Latest_News